# Power Bi DAX: Show data from 6 months past start date

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

i have been having trouble trying to figure out how to show my data past a date that is 6 months past the start date.

I need to show the values that are after the 6 months past the start date.

Each date is different for each person

i have the formula as a calculated column for the 6 months:
+6m = DATEADD('Employee List'[Emp. Dates].[Date], +6, MONTH)

A measure will not work because i cannot apply it to my table as it comes up with an error.

How do i get it to work? 
Should i scrap the +6m column for a new formula?

Comment: is it a calculated column or a custom column? i tried it and it works fine!!

Comment: it is a calculated column. What did you do?

Comment: i selected new column from modelling tab.

Comment: Please see the comment i made on the post below from Przemyslaw Remin

Answer (score 1):

Basic measure:

```
Total Sales = SUM(Sales[Total Sales])
```

As long as you do not provide sample data, it is just guessing what you want. It might be it:

```
YourMeasure =
CALCULATE (
    [Total Sales],
    DATEADD (
        'Employee List'[Emp. Dates].[Date] -- it is better to use here 'Calendar'[Date]
        -6,
        MONTH
    )
)
```

update

This will give you a good start.

Sample data:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjIwMtA1MAQiJR0lQ6VYHZiQEaaQMaaQCaaQKaaQGaaQOaaQBaaQJYaQoQGmEKbrDdFdb4jpR0NkP8YCAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Date = _t, Amount = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}, {"Amount", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

```
Measure = 
var MinDate = CALCULATE( MIN(T[Date]), REMOVEFILTERS(T[Date]) )
var SixMonthAfter = CALCULATE( DATEADD( T[Date], 6 , MONTH ), T[Date] = MinDate )
return
CALCULATE( SUM( T[Amount] ), FILTER( T, T[Date] > SixMonthAfter ) )
```

[image]

Comment: it cant be 6 months before today, it has to be 6 months after start date. My values come under duration (days), the duration must only be shown after the 6 months, before that it shouldnt show, i have measures and filters for the time parameters i want to see. the general gist is that, i need to show duration over a year, 6 months and last month (which i already have). They have an entitlement which is received after the first 6 months, the duration will be taken from the entitlement, if they have gone over their entitlement then they will show in the table.